# Deriving the quadratic equation

Tags: conic-sections

Is there an elegant way to derive the quadratic equation from the definition of a parabola?

In other words, how can it be proven that the set of all points an equal distance away from a focus and a diretrix forms a curve that  can be represented by the equation y=ax^2 ?

I'm sure that this is easy to do using calculus, but I'm wondering if a purely algebraic/geometric proof is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the formula for a parabola in standard position doesn't need calculus:

Position your coordinate system so that the focus is at the point $(0,h)$ where $h\gt 0,$ and the directrix is the line $y=-h.$

Then $(x,y)$ is a point on the parabola iff the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(0,h)$ equals the distance from $(x,y)$ to the line $y=-h,$ and the distance from $(x,y)$ to the line is the same as the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(x,-h),$ which is just $\lvert y+h\rvert.$ It follows that $(x,y)$ is on the parabola iff

$$\sqrt{x^2+(y-h)^2}=\lvert y+h\rvert.$$

Now, applying the facts that both sides of the above equation are non-negative and that $(y+h)^2=\lvert y+h\rvert^2,$ we have that the point $(x,y)$ is on the parabola iff

$$x^2+(y-h)^2=(y+h)^2.$$

Multiplying these out yields

$$x^2+y^2-2hy+h^2=y^2+2hy+h^2,$$

and canceling out the $y^2$ and the $h^2$ gives us

$$x^2=4hy,$$

or

$$y=\frac1{4h}x^2,$$

as desired.

Edit: Thanks to @egreg for a suggestion on improving the presentation of the answer.

Comment: It should be $|y+h|$ in the first equation.

Comment: @egreg I'm on my phone, so just a fast reply... From the geometry of the situation, we know that $y\ge 0,$ so the relevant distance really is $y+h.$

Comment: Yes, but using $|y+h|$ even avoids the need for this justification. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I had some time to incorporate this in the answer now -- thanks for the suggestion.